# access json stucture from another file

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am trying to create a configuration file in order to use some fields in my files.

So, in the config file ( myconfig.json ) :

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path =  require('path');

var Struct = {

    FIELD: 1

};

var Data = JSON.stringify(Struct);

fs.writeFile(__dirname + '/myconfig.json', Data, function (err) {

    if (err) {

        console.log('There has been an error.');
        console.log(err.message);
        return;
      }

     console.log('Configuration saved successfully.')
});
```

In another js file :

```
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');


var Data = fs.readFileSync( __dirname + '/myconfig.json');


console.log("res = ", Data.FIELD);
```

but it prints `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the error was that the first code is a javascript file and not a json .

So, I need to have the `myconfig.json` :

```
{ 

   "FIELDS" : 1
}
```

and use :

`var Data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync( './myconfig.json'));`

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.parse(Data)` should fix it (it's a string at the moment).

Comment: :I though that with stringify it is already an object.Anyway,If I try parse , it gives me `SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 0
` and `undefined:1
/*
^
` and I don't have any `/*` symbols in the above code~

Comment: JSON.stringify turns an object to a string, JSON.parse turns string back to object. Do a console.log on your Data object to verify.

Comment: :Ok, but as I told you the `JSON.parse(Data) ` gives me the above error.

Comment: So what does console.log(Data) log?

Comment: :If I use first the `JSON.parse` it gives me the error above ,else it gives me `<Buffer 2f 2a 0a 0a 41 75 74 68 6f 72 28 73 29 3a 20 46 69 72 73 74 20 4e 61 6d 65 20 4c 61 73 74 20 4e 61 6d 65 0a 44 61 74 65 20 63 72 65 61 74 65 64 3a 20 ... `

Comment: Pass the encoding to readFileSync to get a string.

`var Data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync( __dirname + '/myconfig.json', 'utf8'));`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113163/discussion-between-lee-and-george).

Answer (score -1):

You can just use `require` to get the JSON back from the file:

```
var Data = require(__dirname + '/myconfig.json');
console.log("res = ", Data.FIELD);
```